What difference does it make accepting Youtube's Terms and Conditions?
You can go to youtube.com and watch most videos without logging in or explicitly accepting any terms, and you can watch embedded youtube videos.  To watch age restricted videos and comment you need to register and accept their Terms of Service.
What difference does accepting their Terms of Service make to an individual?
One potential difference that seems possible is for it affect the legality of using a tool like youtube-dl which I believe breaches their terms.  The perfect answer could say if accepting the ToS affects such activity, as well as highlighting other ways it may significantly change your legal situation.

@MichaelHall I have edited the question to attempt to make it clearer.  The example I give is the thing that struck me when I realised that there is a different "state" of using youtube logged in to youtube rather than just google.

YouTube can deny services to anyone for any reason, except illegal discrimination (e.g. due to race or religion). The ToS just makes it explicit which actions they consider reasons to deny you service, but they're not limited. Agreeing to the ToS implies that you understand this policy.
